# C# PDF Generator library with free licence

Tags: gratis, library, c#, wpf, pdf-generation

I need a PDF file generator for WPF applications. I know that the topic has been discussed many times, but there are no details about libraries for free use. The AGPL license version is not an option.

I already have a report template in PDF in the form of HTML / CSS files and XAML vector graphics. Everything was created under IronPdf using Handlebars.

I need a library that works in a similar way. It is a simple application but the report is a few-page with graphics.

Comment: Try http://www.pdfsharp.net/

Answer (score 0):

[Essential PDF](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf) can be used to generate PDFs in WPF applications. It supports binding to data or inserting content as needed. HTML to PDF is also possible using the converter library included in the package.

The entire product is available for free with no limitations through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion